# Div's within another div not visible

Tags: css

I am trying to get some CSS3 effects on my site what I tried to do is this :

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
<div class="header">

<div class="header_box1">
<div class="small_header_box">2222222222 </div>
<div class="small_header_box"> 2222222222</div>
<div class="small_header_box">2222222222 </div>
<div class="small_header_box">2222222222 </div>
</div>


<div class="header_box2">
<div class="small_header_box"> 3333333333</div>
<div class="small_header_box"> 3333333333</div>
<div class="small_header_box"> 3333333333</div>
<div class="small_header_box"> 3333333333</div>
</div>


<div class="header_box3">
<div class="small_header_box"> aaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="small_header_box"> aaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="small_header_box"> aaaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="small_header_box"> aaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header_box1{
 background-color: red;  
}

.header_box2{
 background-color: skyblue;  
}

.header_box3{
 background-color: yellow;  
}
.small_header_box{
 background-color: green;  
   width: 50px;  
    height: 50px; 

    float: left;
}


.header {  
    width: 1000px;  
    height: 300px;  
    margin: 25px auto;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    position: relative;  
    border: 1px solid #000;  
    margin: 25px auto;    

    background-color: #222;  

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
  border-radius: 5px;  

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);  
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);  
}  


   .header div {  
    position: absolute;  
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;  
    margin: 0;  
    line-height: 50px;  
    text-align: center;  
    color: #fff;  
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;  
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);  

   transform:translateX(100%);  
}  

@keyframes left-one {  
    0%  {  
        transform:translateX(100%);  
    }  
    3% {  
        transform:translateX(0);  
    }  
    30% {  
        transform:translateX(0);  
    }  
    31% {  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
    99%{  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
    100%{  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
}  
@keyframes left-two {  
    0% {  
        transform:translateX(100%);  
    }  
    33% {  
        transform:translateX(100%);  
    }  
    34% {  
        transform:translateX(0);          
    }  
    66% {  
        transform:translateX(0);          
    }  
    67%{  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
    100%{  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
} 
@keyframes left-three {  
    0% {  
        transform:translateX(100%);  
    }  
    67% {  
        transform:translateX(100%);  
    }  
    68% {  
        transform:translateX(0);          
    }  
    98% {  
        transform:translateX(0);          
    }  
    99%{  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
    100%{  
        transform:translateX(-100%);  
    }  
}  

.header div:nth-child(1) {  
    animation: left-one 15s ease infinite;  
}  
.header div:nth-child(2) {  
    animation: left-two 15s ease infinite;  
}  
.header div:nth-child(3) {  
    animation: left-three 15s ease infinite;  
}
```

What I want to do is that three div's be in a non stop animation and each div contain four different dives within them. What happens here is, Three Divs do get animated but the four div's within the **header_box(x)** div are not visible. one div acquires all the space available and the remaining three divs are not visible. What should I do so that all the four divs within the Header_box1,Header_box2,Header_box3 are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- set an `height` to the divs, 4 divs in 300px = 75px for each div;
- remove `position: absolute;` or they will always start from 0px, even if with height: 75px;
- remove `float: left;`, that is useless (AND overrided by `position: absolute;`)
- remove `height: 100%;`  from `.header div` rule, that would otherwise "win" against the `.small_header_box` rule.

Of course there are other problems, but as a proof of concept starting from your code (and without understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve), take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nuUm6/

Answer (score 0):

For the div's with class `small_header_box`, the `width:50px` and `height:50px` is not taken, instead `width:100%` and `height:100%` from `.header div` is being taken. Your problem will be solved if you change `.header div` to something more specific.

```
<div class="header">
 <div class="firstLevel header_box1">
  <div class="small_header_box"></div>
  ... 
 </div>
 ....
</div>
```

and in css

```
.header .firstLevel{
    position: absolute;  
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;  
    margin: 0;  
    line-height: 50px;  
    text-align: center;  
    color: #fff;  
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;  
    filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);  
    transform:translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);
}
```

Also you have only floating elements inside `header_box1` ,2 &3 . For the container to fill up the appropriate space you might want to add an empty element with float cleared.

```
<div class="clearFl"></div>
```

and css

```
.clear{
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: `.header div` must be 100% thats what i want. and in this `.header div` their must be four (small_header_box) div that must be visible. How would you do this if u had to do it ?

Comment: by .header div if you want to select only immediate child then give them all a class and use .header .<immediate child classname>. Here, the inner divs(small_header_box) are also getting the .header div properties. That is what is messing up your code. I have updated my answer. Haven't tried out the code though.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what exactly u are trying to make but i think this part of your code is "messed up".

```
.header div {  
position: absolute;  
font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;  
width: 100%;  
height: 100%;  
margin: 0;  
line-height: 50px;  
text-align: center;  
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
transform:translateX(100%);
}
```

By this u are targeting all divs that follow parent with .header class which includes the "small header boxes". Have a look at that part.